# How to print * in triangle?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
     expected output:           ****   my output:      ****
                                ***                    ***
                                **                     **
                                *                      *
                                **                     *
                                ***                    *
                                ****                   ****
```

my code:

```
class  assign17
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            int n=7;
            for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)    
                {
                    if(i+j<=n-4||j==0||i==n-1)
                        System.out.print("*");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

how to get like this?
how to select inner part?
is i have to use another for loop for this or i can make itself in .

Answer (score 2):

This will give you your expected output

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    for (int row=1;row<=7;row+=2){ 
        for (int space=7;space>=row;space-=2){ 
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for (int i=1;i<=row;i++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print("\n"); 
    }

    for (int row=5;row >=1; row-=2){ 
        for (int space=7;space>=row;space-=2){ 
                System.out.print("*");
        }
        for (int i=1;i<=row;i++){ 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print("\n"); 
    }

}
```

I made you four for, it looks like homework so I'm guessing you are more likely to understand it that way.

Explanation:

The two first loop will print you the stars until this

```
****
***
**
*
```

And the others two loops will print the last part of stars

```
**
***
****
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I have added else if condition to your code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (i + j <= n - 4 || j == 0 || i == n - 1)
                System.out.print("*");
            else if (i - j >= n - 4)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you bro! you are the one , who gave me the answer easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can do it recursive with this if I am correct

```
static void printstars(int num){
    if(num > 0){
        for(int t = 0; t<num;t++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
        printstars(num -1);
        for(int t = 0; t<num;t++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of star should print for each iteration is

```
iteration(i)      =>  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
number of star    =>  4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
Math.abs(mid-i)+1 =>  4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

So here i have used inner loop limit to `Math.abs(mid-i)+1`

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  int n = 7;
  int mid = n / 2;

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j< Math.abs(mid-i)+1; j++)
    {
      System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Output :

```
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best solution, but it works ;) I just start with 4 stars and reduce them by 1 each line. If there is just 1 star left, i start to increase the stars again.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int stars = 4;
        boolean lower = true;
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<stars;j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            if(lower) {
                stars--;
                if(stars==0){
                    stars=2;
                    lower = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                stars++;
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class numPtr {
public static void main( String arg[]){
int ck=0,c=2;
    while(c>0){
    if(ck==0){
        for(int i=1,r=5;i<=5;i++,r--){
        for(int j=1;j<=r;j++){
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();        }
        ck++;
   } else{
        for(int i=2;i<=5;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(j);            }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
    c--;
  }
 }
}
```

it will give output like your pattern..

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Comment: the problem is related to `*` not the numbers(1 2 3 4 ...)  stop copy the code from internet. Try your own approach & logic !
Reference link of above source code : https://www.coursehero.com/file/26673161/patterntxt/

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this. Extract out the character used, so if you need to change it in the future. Also, notice the `System.out.println` is only in the first for loop so it is not as complicated. There is a method in charge of building the string you need to print. There are two counters for the number of stars, when you get to zero you switch the the `y` variable and start counting up instead.

```
public static final String CHARACTER = "*";

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x = 4;
    int y = 1;
    boolean hitZero = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        System.out.println(buildStr(hitZero?y:x));

        if(x==1)
          hitZero = true;

       if(hitZero)
         y++;
       else
         x--; 
    }
  }

  private static String buildStr(int count) {
    String res = "";
    for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
      res+=CHARACTER;
    return res;
  }
```

**Output**

```
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
```